# start Android Service and access data in Activity

Tags: android

Dear All;
         I have problem in android development and my situation is as 1st > I want to start my android service when I install my android application how to do this ? 2nd > I want to attach blue-tooth scanning with that android service , Problem is that how I can get (getting data) and display scanned blue-tooth devices names in an activity using service  ?
Means I want to get data from a service that's not bind with any activity ,

Thanks in advance  . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) There's no way to automatically execute code after install.

2) Your best chance is to have the service send a notification, with a pending intent set to start your activity, which will bind to the service. Having a service start directly an activity is good only for phone calls (that is, something that needs immediate attention).

Comment: hi thanks ,I am extending some of your words , you can start your service using Intent actions like call receive,message events and phone booted etc . . . thanks again . . .